# Angularjs app with static pages

Tags: html, angularjs

All,

I have an angularjs app. I have static html site which needs to be loaded first and from that site we have a link which will launch the angular app. Right now I am able to launch the app which I hit the my domain.com but I want to know how to load the static site first instead of loading the angular app.

Comment: create another domain or a subdomain host your angular app in there. subdomain.domain.com will be the angular app.